# Plot empty groups in violin plot

Tags: r, violin-plot, r-base-graphics

I want to compare a number of violinplots. But I am running into a problem for cases where a group is empty: I would like an empty slot plotted so its easier to compare multiple plots.

lets say I have a dataframe:

```
df = data.frame("x"=rep(c(1:4), 3), y=rep(c(1:4), each=3))
df$y[df$x==3] = NA
```

so all of group 3 is NA and I use vioplot to plot it:

```
library(vioplot)
vioplot(y ~ x , df)
```

[image: violin plot]

then I get the plot without group 3. Is there a way I can plot all groups 1:4 but 3 is just empty?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround solution for my specific problem using the `at` argument:

```
df = data.frame("x"=rep(c(1:4), 3), y=rep(c(1:4), each=3))
df$y[df$x==3] = NA

library(vioplot)
vioplot(y ~ x , df, at=unique(df$x[! is.na(df$y)]), xaxt="n")
axis(1, at=unique(df$x))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For the graph, can you change the NAs to 0? e.g.

```
df <- df %>% 
  zoo::na.fill(0)

vioplot(y ~ x , df, ylim = c(1, 4))
```

[image]

Comment: In some cases I may have 0 values in the df though so I don't really want to hard code them in. I suppose I could set it as some other arbitrary number outside the lims but seems a bit hacky

Comment: A value like -999 might be the answer.  As @Limey says, ggplot2 and geom_violin() may be the easier solution, but requires the addition of other geoms to include the other indicators

Answer (score 1):

Or, using `ggplot`...

```
df %>% ggplot() + geom_violin(aes(x=as.factor(x), y=y))
```

Gives

[image]

as does

```
df %>% ggplot() + geom_violin(aes(x, y=y, group=x))
```

Comment: In general I would opt for ggplot but in this specific instance I want to stick to base graphics for speed